# Get every possible combination of 0 and 1 in a 2D array (n x n)

Tags: javascript, arrays, combinations

I am trying to generate a method returning an array of every 2d arrays composed of 0's and 1's in JS in a 2d squared array. Basically, this is the same question as this one : [Make every possible combination in 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275265/make-every-possible-combination-in-2d-array)

But in Javascript, without packages, and add a parameter for the size of the array. Like, a 2x2 would be :

```
let arr = new Array(2).fill(0).map(() => new Array(2).fill(0))
combinations(arr, 2) { ... }

returns : 
[
    [ 
        [0, 0],
        [0, 0]
    ],
    [
        [0, 0],
        [0, 1]
    ],
    [...],
    [
        [1, 1],
        [1, 1]
    ]
]
```

I've tried with recursion but without success, any help would be appreciated.

Edit :

I am tryin =g to write a recursive function to solve this problem.

For now, I have this method :

```
let arr = new Array(2).fill(0).map(() => new Array(2).fill(0))
const generateCombination = (arr, n) => {
    let ret = [];
    let tmp;
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        ret.push(arr)
        arr[i][j] = 1;
        generateCombination(arr.slice(), n-1)
      }
    }
    return ret;
  };
```

which produces this output :

```
[
  [ [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ] ],
  [ [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ] ],
  [ [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ] ],
  [ [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ] ],
]
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You should always _show us_, what you tried ([mre]), even if those attempts were not completely successful.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, the different combinations for an argument *n* can be represented as all the binary sequences for the numbers *0* to the number *2<sup>n<sup>2</sup></sup>-1*.

Because we're dealing with potentially large numbers, the implementation below uses the new [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) data type to represent those numbers. It takes each of those numbers, pads the binary string to a fixed length, and then chunks the string to a two-dimensional array.

Performance is probably not amazing, but I thought it was an interesting approach.

```js
const combinations = (n) => {
  const bits = n ** 2;
  const max = 2n ** BigInt(bits);
  const result = [];
  
  for (let i = 0n; i  < max; i++) {
    const s = i.toString(2).padStart(bits, '0');
    
    result.push([...s].map(Number).reduce((a, _, i, array) => (i % n)
        ? a
        : [...a, array.slice(i, i + n)], []));
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(combinations(2));
```

---

<sup>Note:  `BigInt` is an ECMAScript 2020 feature, so your mileage may vary.</sup>

Comment: I see. This is indeed an interesting approach, you've taken the problem from a different angle than me. I will try this, and maybe try to adapt it to make it a bit simpler to understand. Thank you!

Comment: The most complex looking part is the part that chunks the array, adapted from a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks).

Comment: I've tried your solution, but it crashes on node for n = 5. I guess I need to look for a recursive solution of this problem without going through BigInts as you did. 
Ideally, I would like it to run up until n = 7 or 8

Comment: Well, for n=5, you're looking at 33554432 2-dimensional arrays, so your process might just be running out of memory. It might be better to write a generator function.

Comment: Now, I'm looking at a way to do the exact same thing recursively with 2 loops, how would you achieve that ?
Edit: I have updated the question, and the sample I provided